# How to apply a multiplication of an integer by a byte variable in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using an Elliptic Curve Cryptography library called [fastecdsa](https://fastecdsa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fastecdsa.html) in Python3. I need to multiply an integer  ∈ ℤ (where  is the order of the curve) by a variable z in bytes. For example:

d = 28521545799876732050641018768368512903213511626845294786203503879392791060212

z = b'\xf7LC\xf0\xd5\xc4z\xb7\x84\x02\xd7f\x1b\x1a\xf3\xcf@\xfaf\xd0I\xb0l+t\xf9\x86\xf4\x14(\x00x'

But in the library I can only multiply an integer by a Point on the curve. How can I apply this multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `int.from_bytes` to convert it to int -

```
d = 28521545799876732050641018768368512903213511626845294786203503879392791060212
z = b'\xf7LC\xf0\xd5\xc4z\xb7\x84\x02\xd7f\x1b\x1a\xf3\xcf@\xfaf\xd0I\xb0l+t\xf9\x86\xf4\x14(\x00x'

z_int = int.from_bytes(z,'big')
print(z_int)
```

```
111856022886894735268286046795586803147921415655418728750948058279775245435000
```

Then, after multiplication, you can convert the output to bytes again if required by using `int.to_bytes()` -

```
z_int.to_bytes(32, 'big') #change z_int to the output of multiplication
```

```
b'\xf7LC\xf0\xd5\xc4z\xb7\x84\x02\xd7f\x1b\x1a\xf3\xcf@\xfaf\xd0I\xb0l+t\xf9\x86\xf4\x14(\x00x'
```